# Is it more appropriate to add a new answer or edit the best answer to add new information?

Tags: discussion, edits, obsolete-information

Suppose a new API feature is added to Java which makes a task much easier.  The originally-accepted answer has more than 100 upvotes and is still correct, but it makes no mention of the new feature, which--of course--is only available in newer versions of Java.

Is it more appropriate to add information about that new API feature to the existing "best" answer, or is it better to add a new answer and hope it eventually gets enough upvotes to gain visibility?

**Update: more background on my question.**

The accepted answer and highest-upvoted answers to [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java) mention the complicated ways of copying files in Java prior to Java 7.  Note that I originally didn't notice that the third-highest-upvoted answer mentions Files.copy because the bulk of the answer unnecessarily complicates things by using a different Java 7 feature.

If I happened upon that question when there were only 2 highly-upvoted answers and no existing answers mentioned Files.copy, would it have been more appropriate to edit the "core API only" answer to include a section about Java 7's new Files.copy method, or would it have been better to add a separate answer for the Files.copy method and hope for it to catch up to the others?

For example, the bit added may be as simple as this:

> **Java 7 or newer:**

`Files.copy(Path from, Path to)`

Comment: You could add a version info to the answer if you feel it neccessary. Adding unrelated content or replacing the answer would be too radical.

Comment: @JanDvorak my question doesn't say anything about adding unrelated content or replacing the answer, but perhaps it depends on your interpretation of *unrelated*.  I am purely asking if it is more acceptable to *add* information about a new API feature which dramatically simplifies the solution even though the original, complicated solution is still valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add a new answer. Content changes to other people's answers are generally frowned upon by the StackOverflow community:

**[Guidelines for reviewing Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing#answer-155539)**

> [Reject] Edits that change an answer's explanation or code, with a supposedly 'better' alternative. Even if the proposed solution is better, it should be added as a comment, or a separate answer.

**[Are collaborative answers discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169765/are-collaborative-answers-discouraged#answer-169774)**

> ...edit it for everything *but* the content.

Comment: To clarify, I mean adding more info to an existing answer; not removing or replacing any information.  The mods and high-rep users on android.stackexchange.com actively promote the practice of editing existing answers' content.

Comment: FWIW, I [believe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183626/edit-guidelines-vs-reviewing-practice) that the help documentation encourages wiki-style editing. The SO community has rejected this approach, but other topical sites may have different community guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)