# Edit answers of senior members

Tags: discussion, edits, ethics, high-rep-users

Sometimes I notice any small typing mistake in an answer by a much senior member compared to myself. Mostly what one does is to point out the mistake in a comment and they can fix it with a thanks usually. But is it considered bad (manners) if I go ahead and edit the answer myself I am 100% sure about the error and do not change the logic in any way? Or its still better to let the comments keep flowing where people mention oh this typo that typo.

Do senior members get offended when they see an edit on their post by a much junior one ? (in terms of reputation)

Comment: Nobody will be offended. You edit posts because you care about them. Just make your posts substantial - don't just fix a minor mistake

Comment: @nijansen I think of it otherwise, I think one should only edit someone's post (without their consent) if there is an obviously clear minor mistake that can render the code unable to achieve its task. I think one should not edit someone's answers to add major stuff to them without their consent. Just an opinion

Comment: You got me wrong. A spelling mistake that keeps the code from working **is** a substantial edit. Fixing one obvious typo somewhere in the text may not be.

Comment: That I agree to

Comment: related: [Editing Philosophy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194728/165773)

Comment: @HankyPanky - "Senior" members? You've got nearly 9k rep - dude, you *are* a "senior" member. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everybody agrees to collaborative editing when they signup and contribute. Everybody makes typos and fumbles words/grammar from time to time.

Feel free to make substantive constructive edits with the [usual guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) to any post that you see which needs it.

Answer (score 10):

**No not at all, unless it affects their point of view**.  I have seen some comments in SO where Jon Skeet (MVP in SO) welcomes this.  **Most people are open to edit their posts (which I have seen in their profile under "About Me"**). But you should give some time to them for correcting their typo because they maybe fast to show their answer first.

Comment: Boy you are spending so much time editing this answer again and again :) can almost predict now lol. Jus kidding

Comment: "MVP in SO" is like saying "Michael Jordan is a good basketball player". :D

Comment: ahahahahahahaha

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd MVP == **Master** Vice President

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd True I shouldn't have said that here :).  But it makes him special(in my opinion).

Comment: @ColeJohnson I would use MLU which stands for Most Legendary User... master is still an understatement. `@`user1671639 - fair enough, whatever sails your boat. ;)

Comment: Or, "floats your boat"... because, rhyme.